# Conversion function to delete class object?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write a conversion function for a class that returns a pointer and which can also be used by delete expression to delete my object? if so, how can i do that?

Comment: I assume you're returning `this`? Otherwise it's not possible.

Comment: Do you mean `class T { operator T*() { return this; } };`?  However, I struggle to think of a situation where this would be useful or advisable.

Comment: Makes no sense. An object doesn't get to decide how it was allocated, so it shouldn't expose any logic to deallocate it in any specific way.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I think that would be it, but I don't understand why would i do that?

Comment: @user974191: You wouldn't do that, normally.  Like I said, there probably isn't any good use for it.

Comment: @user974191 indeed, great question. Why *would* you do this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I came up with this from (5.3.5/1) which refers to conversion function. but I don't see the point.

Comment: @user974191: That statement means that you can say `delete a;` when `a` is of type `X` and there is a function `Y * X::operator() const` that produces *some* pointer(-to-object). Typically this has nothing to do with `a` itself.

Comment: @KerrekSB: do conversion functions have return types? Like in yours which returns Y*. should it be `X::operator Y*()` ? Does it delete a member of class X?

Comment: Well, yes, they return the type to which they convert, `Y*` in this case. The operator doesn't otherwise have a name.

Comment: @KerrekSB: One more question, wouldn't it break encapsulation if you return a pointer to a private member?!

Comment: @user974191: Yes. Nobody said that everything about this question is not terrible design :-)

Answer (score 1):

For delete X to work, X must be of a type (or shared base type w/ virtual destructor) of the original object.  So normally you would never need such an operator, as it would only work if you're doing an implicit cast to base, which needs no conversion operator.

And for anything else the answer is effectively "no".

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Thing1 : public Base
{
public:
  ... whatever ...
}

class Thing2 : public Base
{
public:
  ...
}
```

You can do stuff:

```
Thing1 * t = new Thing1;
Base * b = t; // okay
delete b;  // okay, deletes b (which is also t)
           // BECAUSE we provided a virtual dtor in Base,
           // otherwise a form of slicing/memory loss/bad stuff would occur here;
Thing2 * t2 = new Thing2;
Thing1 * t1 = t2; // error: won't compile (a t2 is not a t1)
                  // and even if we cast this into existence, 
                  // or created an operator that provided this
                  // it would be "undefined behavior" - 
                  // not "can be deleted by delete operator"
```